# Automatic Chrome opening on session start - windows 10

Tags: windows, google-chrome, windows-10

I just want Google Chrome to automatically launch itself when I log into my win 10 session. Is that possible ? I saw a LOT of people wanting to disable this behavior on some systems, but none who tried to actually enable it, so couldn't find a solution yet.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As described [here](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-add-or-remove-startup-apps-in-windows-10/) go to

> C:\Users\Your user name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start
>   Menu\Programs\Startup

(or on Run `shell:Startup` )and add a shortcut of chrome at this folder

Answer (score 6):

Windows 10 has a startup folder in the Start Menu in which you can drop shortcuts to applications you want to start automatically.

In previous versions of Windows it was pretty easy to find but Windows 10 has made it a little more difficult.

1. Press the Windows key and R together to open the run dialog
2. Type in `shell:startup` and press OK, an explorer window will open up
3. Copy and paste a shortcut to Chrome from your desktop to this window.
4. Restart your PC and Chrome will automatically launch.

There is also a special mode called [kiosk mode](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt219050%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) that will limit Windows to a single program. This is usually used for public access terminals.

Answer (score 3):

#### I want to launch a program when I log in

Add a shortcut to the program you want to start (chrome in your case) to:

`C:\Users\Your user name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

---

#### How to add or remove startup apps in Windows 10

> Startup items for the current user are stored usually at two locations: the Registry and the special "Startup" folder. The Startup folder is an easier way to manage apps. To add or remove an app from the Startup folder, you need to do the following:
>
> - Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> shortcut keys together and type the following into the Run box:
>
>   shell:Startup
>
> The text above is a special shell command which will open the Startup
>   folder for you directly.
>
> [image: the startup folder in Windows 10]
>
> The Startup folder is located here:
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Your user name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
> ```
>
> Just copy and paste a shortcut in this folder so that the app loads
>   when Windows boots. To remove the application from the Startup folder,
>   delete the appropriate shortcut.
>
> [image: remove startup apps]

Source [How to add or remove startup apps in Windows 10](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-add-or-remove-startup-apps-in-windows-10/)